# Switching between Image Sequence and Movie Clip for Compositing

Tags: masking

So I used an image sequence as a video and edited it using masks. However, I want to insead use a movie clip because I will be able to do more things with it.
However, when I replaced the image node with the movie clip node, the scale of the video was changed and all of my masks were misplaced. I don't want to go back frame by frame and change each mask, but I also don't want to render the current video (with the image sequence) because I want to be able to edit the masks if I wanted down the road.

With Image Sequence:
[image]

With Movie Clip:
[image]

the video seems larger, however I can't zoom out for some reason.
Also, the masks seem to be in the right place, but they do not render as such. I didn't move them or anything, they were automatically there when I put in the movie clip.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, found a workaround. 
Just used a scale node on the image.